# Adding HTTP header to HttpSoapClientProtocol

Tags: .net, http, soap, header, client

I'm generating a web service client dynamically (runtime) from a wsdl using ServiceDescriptionImporter.

Everything works great until I try to invoke a service that requires authentication (Basic). I can't find any way to add basic auth header to the request sent by the client I generated.

I have tried the following but it doesn't work. I still get a 401:

```
var webClient = obj as HttpSoapClientProtocol;
CredentialCache mycache = new CredentialCache();
// Credentials are specified here
mycache.Add(new Uri("http://localhost:9999/MyService"), "Basic", new NetworkCredential("username", "password"));
webClient.Credentials = mycache;
```

How can I add a HTTP header to the webClient (HttpWebClientProtocol)?

/Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I was almost right. Just needed to set `PreAuthenticate` to true.

Here is the correct code:

```
var webClient = obj as HttpWebClientProtocol;
NetworkCredential netCredential = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9999/MyService");
ICredentials credentials = netCredential.GetCredential(uri, "Basic");
webClient.Credentials = credentials;
webClient.PreAuthenticate = true;
```